# How to redirect to view page using mongoDB and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I am new with `node.js`, `mongoDB` and `jade`.

To redirect to `userlist` page I have following route in `/routes/index.js`

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

This route redirects me to `userlist` page. There I display a list of all users. Here I have a link on each record to view details:

following is my userlist.jade

```
extends layout

    block content
        h1.
            User List
        ul
            each user, i in userlist
                li
                    a(href="/viewuser/id/#{user._id}")=user.username
```

This:

```
a(href="/viewuser/id/#{user._id}")=user.username
```

Gives me:

```
<a href="/viewuser/id/56aca898d9b0de79214ae381">Dhara</a>
```

Now I don't know what route should be there for view details on click of the link and how to get selected record data for view screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a clear and distributed stack **MEAN.js**, with a [yeoman constructor](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) that will help you to build secure and good-practice programming applications.

This is the way I get a concrete user data. It´s a little more spread than your code but it´s clear.

Hope it helps!

**routes.js**

```
app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));
```

**api/user/index.js**

```
var controller = require('./user.controller');
router.get('users/:id', controller.show);
```

**user.controller.js:**

```
// Get a single user
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!user) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(user);
  });
};
```

then I´ll call for a user with an url like `users/xxxxxx` where xxxx is the user id. Then if you want to do it like `/viewuser/id/xxxxxx` you will need to change the route like this:

**api/user/index.js**

```
var controller = require('./user.controller');
router.get('viewuser/id/:id', controller.show);
```

**user.controller.js:**

```
// Get a single user
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!user) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(user);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro it helps me.

Comment: u welcome!!! I strongly recommend to use that kind of stacks!!! they are correctly distrbuted and will help you to understand the possibilities of MEAN!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to specify the view in your app server file

`app.get('/userlist', function(req, res){
  res.render('userlist', {
    title: 'Your_Title'
  });
});`

I hope to be helpful!